# Google Cloud Builder trigger giving "No such blob" error

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform

I am setting up a Google Cloud Build trigger. I choose GitHub, authenticate to GitHub, choose the repository I want to use as a trigger, and then choose "Cloud Build configuration file (yaml or json)" and leave "Cloud Build configuration file location" set to the default of `cloudbuild.yaml`.

However, when I trigger a run by choosing "Run trigger" Google Cloud Builder gives me the error

```
Failed to trigger build: cloud.mygcpproject/github_example_myproject:cloudbuild.yaml: No such blob refs/heads/master:cloudbuild.yaml
```

But the file `cloudbuild.yaml` *does* exist in that repository. I have tried deleting and recreating the trigger many times, always with the same result.

Here is the top-level contents:

```
total 72
drwxr-xr-x 8 rlandster rlandster 4096 Apr  9 20:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 rlandster rlandster 4096 Apr  3 19:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 rlandster rlandster 4096 Mar 10 11:54 aws
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster   74 Dec 11 18:43 aws.mdwn
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster  364 Apr  9 20:11 cloudbuild.yaml
drwxr-xr-x 3 rlandster rlandster 4096 Mar 11 04:56 debian
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster   42 Mar  9 19:56 debian.mdwn
drwxr-xr-x 3 rlandster rlandster 4096 Feb  2 13:26 gcp
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster   54 Feb  2 13:22 gcp.mdwn
drwxr-xr-x 2 rlandster rlandster 4096 Mar  3 10:15 git
drwxr-xr-x 8 rlandster rlandster 4096 Apr 17 05:08 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster   48 Mar  3 10:15 git.mdwn
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster 2699 Mar 11 19:42 gpg.mdwn
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster   89 Mar 11 19:41 index.mdwn
drwxr-xr-x 2 rlandster rlandster 4096 Mar  3 10:15 ldap
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster   46 Mar  3 10:15 ldap.mdwn
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster 1242 Mar 10 20:51 local.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 rlandster rlandster   23 Dec 11 18:41 README.md
```

To make sure that the `cloudbuild.yaml` is in the remote, I do a `git clone` of the remote repository and then list the objects:

```
$ git ls-tree refs/heads/master
100644 blob ba1d886a431eeefae6e86ea82e4b32f58e555482    README.md
100644 blob 255991c16bfa8ceda1f910ca8c2c9a76176074cc    aws.mdwn
040000 tree 1b65cfb9fab80cb19ca874f24eec18f4a33441ba    aws
100644 blob f9c0fa22a6b36daae4a258825fa14ee970c55db9    cloudbuild.yaml
100644 blob 1a1720e89e8f7e5782404d1dcde409f93fa2b3a3    debian.mdwn
040000 tree be830bc70f66503f3723b68293d1c2be171ba491    debian
100644 blob e24269417aa5afaa14b8d77a2af6d484bb132e91    gcp.mdwn
040000 tree c9470904cac2c9b4ecfc2d129a295414d3f91b35    gcp
100644 blob 96a0c8fc32b7ccb9d16a68beb20f471e4b3e2c8f    git.mdwn
040000 tree 84249e1a63519cfc1865f241caa03ff2c8276f70    git
100644 blob fe6ec42d23f3a35945f16ebe2f088c937b6a4fe0    gpg.mdwn
100644 blob 22c4923e6233039f7a5280eeeeeeb358765989dc    index.mdwn
100644 blob baa1399e4948a8f1456fa80100f08a369ce84439    ldap.mdwn
040000 tree d777c11680977d00b244877e6ee43a548c6d956a    ldap
100644 blob b30f876c9c054b304d30d584e3407da0f940419c    local.css

$ git cat-file -s refs/heads/master:cloudbuild.yaml   
364
```

UPDATE: While manual triggering still results in the same "No such blob" error, a git push *does* trigger a successful build. So, it is just manual triggering that is not working.

Comment: Can you please share your repository structure? (e.g. by running `ls`)

Comment: Added top-level directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

That error was reported before [in this article](https://medium.com/@zyanting18/hi-josh-3944245434bc)

> Next, create this `cloudbuild.yaml` file in the root of your repo.
>   The contents will be instructions for the Cloud Build executor where we will write our gsutil command. The rest of this tutorial assumes your git repository has at least the following structure (in bold):

```
.

├── cloudbuild.yaml
├── dags
│   └── my_dag.py ... etc
└── plugins
```

Make sure, through a git status, that:

- you are on the master branch
- the file `cloudbuild.yml` is actually tracked (meaning an add+commit was done)

In the article comments, the user reported:

> Figured, because the source repository did not pick up `cloudbuild.yaml` when I made my commits.
>   I think this happened because I’ve set up a trigger based on a certain path and it just ignored that commit.

Comment: The file `cloudbuild.yaml` is, indeed, committed and on the (only) branch `master`. So my issue must be caused by something else.

Comment: @rlandster strange indeed. I would double check the name of the file `cloudbuild.yaml` and not `cloudbuild.yaml ` (with an extra invisible space).

Comment: I can tell that I do not have an invisible character via the command `git cat-file -s refs/heads/master:cloudbuild.yaml` that outputs the size of the file. I have updated my original post with some extra information that might be helpful.